# Determining Error Bars on Normal Data from Sensor with Rated Error

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, experiment-design, descriptive-statistics, measurement-error

You are using a sensor to take temperature measurements at 10 Hz. You sample for 100 seconds and end up with 1000 samples. Upon analyzing a histogram of the data, you see that it appears normal with a mean of 100 K, and a standard deviation of 10 K. A time history of the data appears to show a slightly noisy, but flat signal. This makes sense because you were expecting the temperature to remain constant across the 100 seconds.

From this data, you have two goals:

1. Estimate the true temperature, assuming it was constant for the 100-second sampling duration.
2. Provide a 95% confidence interval of this true temperature.

Your goals are complicated by the fact that the sensor has a rated accuracy of +/-1% of its full-scale range. This range is 50 K - 150 K, so its accuracy is +/-1 K.

How do you factor in the sensor's rated accuracy to the standard confidence interval formula?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after doing some research. In particular, the answer by Sonia Gaita to this discussion on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-combine-instrument-uncertainty-with-random-uncertainty) was helpful. The answer cites the following guide by the Joint Committee for Guides in Metrology (JCGM): ["Evaluation of measurement data — Guide to the expression of uncertainty in measurement."](https://www.iso.org/sites/JCGM/GUM/JCGM100/C045315e-html/C045315e.html?csnumber=50461)

Using the terminology from this guide, the measured data scatter is Type A uncertainty. As described in section 4.2, the "standard uncertainty" associated with the scatter is the population standard deviation divided by the number of samples. In my case, this would be:

$$
u_A = \frac{10 K}{1000} = 0.01 K
$$

The error due to the sensor's rated accuracy is Type B uncertainty. As described in section 4.3.7, when no other information is given about the sensor's error except upper and lower bounds, it is reasonable to assume that the probability density function is uniform across the range of the bounds and zero elsewhere. The standard uncertainty is, therefore:

$$
u_B = \frac{1 K}{\sqrt{3}} \approx 0.57735 K
$$

Assuming these uncertainties are uncorrelated, they can be combined to form the overall standard uncertainty, as described in section 5:

$$
u_C = \sqrt{{u_A}^2+{u_B}^2} \approx 0.57744 K
$$

The confidence interval can be found by multiplying the overall standard uncertainty by a factor $k$, which is typically a value between 2 and 3. Without more information regarding the exact distributions of the Type A and Type B uncertainties, it is impossible to determine exactly what the 95% confidence interval should be. However, in practice, situations that call for a 95% confidence interval typically use $k=2$. Therefore, a reasonable answer would be:

$$
T \approx 100 K \pm 1.15487 K
$$